# Is there a way to add the ability to browse for files in a select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

so I have a select menu that allows the user to choose several ways to pick a file for what they're trying to do. They can create a file on their own, inline, they can pick from existing files or they can browse their computer to upload a file. When they choose this last option from the select menu I want it to automatically launch the browser/OS's 'file picker' dialog, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get that to work across OS's and browsers. Technically I only need it to work for FF and Chrome (latest versions) on Windows and OSX.

Here's an example of what I'm looking to do, even though this doesn't even come remotely close to working (the file-input class hides all of the typical file picker stuff browsers add in. So this just looks like a simple text string):

```
<select>
    <option value="note" class="disabled">Select File</option>
    <option value="import">
     <label id="add-computer-button" for="fileupload" class="file-input-button-spirent">Import File</label>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="browse" accept="image/*" class="file-input-button" />
    </option>
    <option value="library">Select from Library</option>
    <option value="custom">Build file</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"> ?

Comment: @JMusic This limits the upload to image file types.

Comment: invalid html putting `<input>` in `<option>`. Use a different UI than `<select>` or move the file button

Comment: I know it's not valid HTML... I said I know it "doesn't even come remotely close to working" That's why I'm asking for help :)

Comment: I suppose ultimately @charlietfl is right though, just need to build a custom control that looks like a select menu... was hoping there was a way to use the standard select control, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<script>
 $("#selectList").on("change", function(){
   var x = $("option:selected",this).val();
    if(x=="import"){
     $("#fileUpload").click();
    }
  });
</script>

<select id="selectList">
    <option value="note" class="disabled">Select File</option>
    <option value="import"></option>        
    <option value="library">Select from Library</option>
    <option value="custom">Build file</option>
  </select>
     <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="upload" accept=""  style="display:none;">
```

Comment: What browser(s) did you test that on?

Comment: Can't say I do a full browser compatibility / QA testing on my Stack answers. But this work in across later versions IE, Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: Tested on Safari + Chrome (mac) and it doesn't work.